# Optimise rendering of multiple copies of the same .svg file

Tags: svg

I am using the `svg` package to include flag emojis as .svg files in my text with `\includesvg{}`. However, since I need to render a lot of flags which are the same, and each flag takes a lot of time, it hits the Overleaf compile time limit. Is there a way of optimising the rendering of repeats of the same .svg file, so that it doesn't time out? Unfortunately I can't use `\emoji` as the class file I am using requires pdflatex as a compiler.

```
\documentclass{article}

% SVG figures
\usepackage{svg}
\def\sweflag{\includesvg[width=1.5em]{flags/se}}

\begin{document}

Sweden is great! \sweflag\sweflag\sweflag\sweflag\sweflag\sweflag\sweflag\sweflag\sweflag

\end{document}
```

[Download for Sweden flag .svg.](https://images.emojiterra.com/google/noto-emoji/unicode-15/color/svg/1f1f8-1f1ea.svg)

Comment: convert it once to pdf and then use \includegraphics.

Comment: In case the exact shape of your image does not matter, you could use https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emoji

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I need to use pdflatex to conform with Elsevier template, otherwise I'd have used `\emoji` for sure

Answer (score 2):

Pkg `xsavebox` might be of help:

```bash
time pdflatex --shell-escape swedenXsbox.tex
...
real    0m0.551s
user    0m0.510s
sys 0m0.039s
```

`swedenXsbox.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

% SVG figures
\usepackage{svg}

\usepackage{xsavebox}
\xsbox{sweflag}{\includesvg[width=1.5em]{flags/se}}

\begin{document}

Sweden is great!
\foreach \i in {1,...,600} {\thesweflag\space}

\end{document}
```

whereas

```latex
time pdflatex --shell-escape swedenDef.tex
...
real    0m2.733s
user    0m2.598s
sys 0m0.119s
```

`swedenDef.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

% SVG figures
\usepackage{svg}
\def\sweflag{\includesvg[width=1.5em]{flags/se}}

\begin{document}

Sweden is great!
\foreach \i in {1,...,600} {\sweflag\space}

\end{document}
```